Deriving Cauchy's product formula for finite series
Say we have this summation
$$\mathrm S=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$$
I wanted to derive Cauchy's product formula for summations (finite series) to find an alternative expression for $\mathrm S^2$, namely,
$$\mathrm S^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_i a_j$$
My attempt at the formula would start by defining $j=i+k$ (although usually they set $k=i+j$). This definition reminds us of $y=x+k$ which means that when $k>0$, then $j>i$, when $k=0$, $i=j$ (diagonal terms) and $j<i$ for when $k<0$. It follows that the equivalent double sum in this new index is
$$\sum_{k=0}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i a_{k+i}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} a_i a_{k+i}+\sum_{k=-1}^{-n+1}\sum_{i=1-k}^{n} a_i a_{k+i}$$
Now my question is how can I convert the above into the product formula which looks somewhat like
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_ja_{i-j}$$
